# Is there a way to format JSON commas that makes merge GUI tools happy?

Tags: json, git, merge

I'm working with a large team on a project that has a lot of JSON configuration files. They get changed frequently, and, of course, there a lot of merge conflicts. Our devs use a bunch of different GUI merge tools to choose which lines to use in a merge.

A lot of our merges are resolved by "choose both lines" (see example below). It seems during a lot of these merges, the GUI merge tools don't know they need to add a comma to make the result syntactically-correct JSON. Our devs have to add the comma in manually, and all-to-often, they forget to do so (again, see example below).

Branch A

```
{
     "enabled": true,
     "apiUrl":"https://myapi.com/v1"
}
```

Branch B

```
{
    "enabled": true,
    "clientID": "abc123123"
}
```

Merged Branch:

```
{
     "enabled": true,
     "apiUrl":"https://myapi.com/v1" <=== oops, no comma
     "clientID": "abc123123"
}
```

Is there a way to format JSON to prevent this from happening? I'm thinking this way (see below - commas in between lines of properties) might solve the issue, but I'm not sure. It also seems to waste a lot of space.

```
{
     "enabled": true
     ,
     "apiUrl":"https://myapi.com/v1"
     ,
     "clientID": "abc123123"
}
```

What are my options here, short of telling our staff to be a little more careful while resolving merge conflicts.

Comment: It's not a solution, but proper `pre-commit` checks would help flag this problem before someone commits a change with a syntax error.

Comment: Any thoughts on whether an alternative format such as YAML would solve my problems? My other big gripe with JSON is the lack of ability to comment.

Comment: YAML would help this specific issue since there is no commas to maintain - each line can be an individual entity and the merge conflicts would be resolved automatically (for the scenario you described)

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, it seems that the real issue here is human error :)

Asking your staff to "be a little more careful" when making changes to the code is a good idea but it probably won't prevent this issue in the future.
I don't think that there would be a way to automatically "fix" the conflicts since once the JSON is missing a comma it is not longer a valid JSON and might as well be a normal unstructured text file. Consider the possibility that what renders the JSON invalid is an *actual* mistake and not just a borked merge by missing a comma.

One thing I can suggest is to implement a ["pre-commit" git hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks) that would attempt to `JSON.parse` (or something similar) the files and if an error occurred, you can block the commit with an appropriate message.

It should be noted that you are not actually preventing the errors from happening - rather you'll be able to detect them and notify the users before the problematic changes are saved.

Answer (score 4):

For what it's worth, your proposed solution is similar to the Haskell idiom of *starting* non-initial lines with commas.

```
{
     "enabled": true
     ,"apiUrl":"https://myapi.com/v1"
     ,"clientID": "abc123123"
}
```

The benefit in this case is that it seems to cover the common case of multiple developers *appending* new keys, leaving the first line untouched.

Comment: What an interesting approach! You could have a default initial line for each JSON that is created and then just **always** prepend additional entries with a comma.

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio also does that for queries it generates, which makes it easier to comment out non-initial lines. But wait, JSON has no comments...

Comment: I think that if the root cause is human error, this approach would suffer the same fate - people forgetting to prepend their lines with a comma...

Comment: @Lix Certainly; it depends on an assumption that changes never involve the first line. But if that assumption holds, then the rule is "always prepend a new key with a comma", just like the rule "always end a new key with a comman" would work if JSON allowed an optional trailing comma for the list of key/value pairs. It doesn't *eliminate* this particular source of human error, but hopefully it avoids more cases of it.